# manipulating tab-delimited table within unix environment

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a tab-delimited .txt, `map.txt` file that looks like this:

```
#SampleID   BarcodeSequence LinkerPrimerSequence    sample_type Description geneticSampleID
OSBS.087.39.M.32.18.20140227    TCCCTTGTCTCC    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A1   OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
OSBS.048.41.M.37.33.20140227    ACGAGACTGATT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A2   OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
OSBS.048.23.M.15.31.20140227    GCTGTACGGATT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A3   OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
OSBS.047.21.M.20.3.20140227 ATCACCAGGTGT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A4   OSBS_047-M-20-3-20140227-gen
OSBS.119.23.M.18.38.20140227    TGGTCAACGATA    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A5   OSBS_119-M-18-38-20140227-gen
OSBS.047.41.M.22.36.20140227    ATCGCACAGTAA    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A6   OSBS_047-M-22-36-20140227-gen
OSBS.087.41.M.40.21.20140227    GTCGTGTAGCCT    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A7   OSBS_087-M-40-21-20140227-gen
OSBS.048.21.M.5.11.20140227 AGCGGAGGTTAG    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A8   OSBS_048-M-5-11-20140227-gen
OSBS.119.39.M.27.5.20140227 ATCCTTTGGTTC    CGGCTGCGTTCTTCATCGATGC  soil    Plate 1A9   OSBS_119-M-27-5-20140227-gen
```

I would like to generate a new file where the first line is the entry in `geneticSampleID` and the second line is `BarcodeSequence`, such that the output would look like this:

```
>OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
TCCCTTGTCTCC
>OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
ACGAGACTGATT
>OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
GCTGTACGGATT
```

...etc for all the lines in `map.txt`. So, if `map.txt` had 100 lines (or 101 with the header), then `output.txt` would have 200 lines.

I know this is probably a pretty trivial manipulation, but I am currently very stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR>1{printf ">%s\n%s\n", $6, $2}' file
```

```
>OSBS_087-M-32-18-20140227-gen
TCCCTTGTCTCC
>OSBS_048-M-37-33-20140227-gen
ACGAGACTGATT
>OSBS_048-M-15-31-20140227-gen
GCTGTACGGATT
>OSBS_047-M-20-3-20140227-gen
ATCACCAGGTGT
>OSBS_119-M-18-38-20140227-gen
TGGTCAACGATA
>OSBS_047-M-22-36-20140227-gen
ATCGCACAGTAA
>OSBS_087-M-40-21-20140227-gen
GTCGTGTAGCCT
>OSBS_048-M-5-11-20140227-gen
AGCGGAGGTTAG
>OSBS_119-M-27-5-20140227-gen
ATCCTTTGGTTC
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, pretty trivial:

```
tail -n +2 map.txt | cut -f1,2 | tr '\t' '\n'
```

That gives me:

```
OSBS.087.39.M.32.18.20140227
TCCCTTGTCTCC
OSBS.048.41.M.37.33.20140227
ACGAGACTGATT
OSBS.048.23.M.15.31.20140227
GCTGTACGGATT
OSBS.047.21.M.20.3.20140227
ATCACCAGGTGT
OSBS.119.23.M.18.38.20140227
TGGTCAACGATA
OSBS.047.41.M.22.36.20140227
ATCGCACAGTAA
OSBS.087.41.M.40.21.20140227
GTCGTGTAGCCT
OSBS.048.21.M.5.11.20140227
AGCGGAGGTTAG
OSBS.119.39.M.27.5.20140227
ATCCTTTGGTTC
```

The `tail` takes the first line out.  The `cut` gives only the first two fields.  The `tr` replaces the tab with a carriage return.

Comment: awesome, thank you. The only reason I didn't accept this answer over the other one is because it did not have the leading `>` character on the sample IDs.

Comment: Can add `sed 's/^/>/'` before the `tr` if you want that.